# API Design is it best practice to tell the consumer of an API to allocate the memory?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to implement an application software in C. i end up designing multiple layers. From each layer exposes an its own API and can invoke another layers's API too.

```
Example:
Layer 1:
      // invoking layer2 API.
      // allocating mystrcuture here
      getDetailsOf (mystructure);

Layer 2:
      getDetailsOf ( mystrcuture)
      {
             Fill up the details in mystrcuture, 
      }
```

I have followed the above approach. The other way would be to release the responsibility of allocating mystrcuture to getDetailsOf() function, and let him to return new allocated mystructure.

Kindly help me which is the right way of doing ?

Comment: Another option would be to return an object of `mystructure`'s type.

Comment: Which language are you talking about? That's a fundamental part of your question which you shouldn't underestimate! That said, do you have a simple aggregate with all public members or do you have an opaque type that can only be manipulated through a bunch of functions?

Comment: @juanchopanza while for c++ thats an option, it would afaik be pretty bad/wrong practice in plain C.

Comment: @Zaibis Ah, I hadn't realised OP wants to write the code in two languages ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes; I think that the caller should allocate the memory (of course, you'll need to take a pointer to the structure).  You know the exact size needed, so why not let the caller allocate memory as they see fit?  No reason to enforce dynamic allocation here.

EDIT: This answer is C-centric.  You should specify which langauge you are talking about here.

Answer (score 1):

As C++ allows to return an object that could take care of deallocation of internal parts in its destructor, I assume your question concerns a C compatible API.

Both approaches are acceptable. If mystructure is simple enough (see below), the caller should deal with allocation and deallocation and pass a pointer to below layer ; if it is too complex, callee should allocate memory for it and return a pointer that caller should free when it no longer needs it.

IMHO, the rule should be if all the necessary memory is of constant size or knows before call, allocation should be caller responsability. If it is not the case, for example char arrays of variable length, bitmaps of arbitrary size, ..., it should be callee responsability.

This answer can be mitigated in the interests of harmonization, if you prefere that all the functions of an API use same logic.